# No me puedo conectar a MySql con Visual Studio 2013 para trabajar en Asp.net MVC 4 web y en E.F

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Quiero conectarme a una base de datos con entity framework a una base de datos con MySql yog Ultimate, pero no me resulta. Empece por agregar los dlls:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

E incluso agrego a la webconfig lo siguiente:

Pero no muestra la base de datos de MySql:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que sucede, que falta, como se logra la conección

Comment: lograste algún avance?

Comment: no, supongo que debe ser la version del dll, pero no he probado aun

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es un driver que conecte MySQL con ASP.NET 
En este caso el servidor es tu computadora personal.

Puedes descargar los drivers, luego de instalarlos cierra Visual Studio y vuelvelo a abrir. MySQL debería de salir en la lista de valores de Motores de Bases de Datos para que realices tu conexión

[Download Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.2.html)

[Instrucciones de Instalación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation.html)